# Как исправить данную ошибку "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_of_lawyer_answer' referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python, selenium

Как исправить данную ошибку "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_of_lawyer_answer' referenced before assignment" ?
Как я понял, она возбуждается из-за того, что 'name_of_lawyer_answer' не присвоено значения, но я это вызываю.
Сам код вот:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as TE
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


def get_url(driver): # перехожу по урлу на нужный сайт
    driver.get('https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?order=recency&page=1&search_topic_advice_search[content_type]=Q%26A&search_topic_advice_search[query]=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search[state]=CA')
    time.sleep(3)


def get_content(driver): # собираю информация со страницы
    try:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='qa-body-display']/p[@class='a button btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']/span[@class='icon-chevron-down-after-blue']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        mores_lawyer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']")
        for more_lawyer in mores_lawyer:
            more_lawyer.click()
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

    question_short = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']")
    question_long = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@itemprop='text']")
    date_question_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/ul[@class='inline-list']/li[@class='text-muted small hidden-xs']")
    name_lawyers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    lawyer_answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row answer-body']/div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='answer-body-9088247']")
    dates = []
    names = []
    answers = []
    for lawyer_answer in lawyer_answers:
        name_of_lawyer_answer = lawyer_answer.text
        answers.append(name_of_lawyer_answer)
    for date_question_post in date_question_posts:
        name_data_question_post = date_question_post.text
        dates.append(name_data_question_post)
    for name_lawyer in name_lawyers:
        name_of_lawyer = name_lawyer.text
        names.append(name_of_lawyer)

    name_short = question_short.text
    name_long = question_long.text

    print("\nQuestion: ",name_short, "\n" ,name_long, "\n")
    for date in dates:
        print(name_data_question_post)
    for name in names:
        print("\nLawyer name: ", name_of_lawyer)
    for answer in answers:
        print("\nLawyer answer: ", name_of_lawyer_answer)

    return (name_short, name_long, name_of_lawyer,name_of_lawyer_answer, name_data_question_post)


def page_pagination(driver):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-2']/a[@class='block-link']")
    urls = []
    for div in divs:
        url = div.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url)
    for url_1 in urls:
        trans = driver.get(url_1)
        time.sleep(2)
        get_content(driver)
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    get_url(driver)
    page_pagination(driver)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Расширь пожалуйста вопрос полной сводкой ошибки

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\geckodriver\avvo_parser.py", line 82, in <module>
main()
File "D:\geckodriver\avvo_parser.py", line 77, in main
page_pagination(driver)
File "D:\geckodriver\avvo_parser.py", line 70, in page_pagination
get_content(driver)
File "D:\geckodriver\avvo_parser.py", line 58, in get_content
return (name_short, name_long, name_of_lawyer, name_of_lawyer_answer, name_data_question_post)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_of_lawyer_answer' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Переменная name_of_lawyer_answer у Вас инициализируется и вызывается в разных областях видимости.
В этом блоке нет доступа к переменной name_of_lawyer_answer:

```
for answer in answers:
    print("\nLawyer answer: ", name_of_lawyer_answer)
```

Должно быть, видимо, так:

```
for answer in answers:
    print("\nLawyer answer: ", answer)
```

Comment: проблему это не решило, а ошибку при return всё ровно возбуждает

Comment: Там не одна ошибка. С переменной name_of_lawyer та же ситуация.
Трейсбек ошибки изменился?

Comment: нет, он полностью такой же

Comment: не могу понять почему грешит именно на это, ведь во всём остальном использую туже структуру

Comment: проблема решена

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за потраченное время и всяческую помощь, проблема была решена заменой элемента, который нужно было найти (В lawyer_answers):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as TE
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


def get_url(driver): # перехожу по урлу на нужный сайт
    driver.get('https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?order=recency&page=1&search_topic_advice_search[content_type]=Q%26A&search_topic_advice_search[query]=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search[state]=CA')
    time.sleep(3)


def get_content(driver): # собираю информация со страницы
    try:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='qa-body-display']/p[@class='a button btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']/span[@class='icon-chevron-down-after-blue']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        mores_lawyer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']")
        for more_lawyer in mores_lawyer:
            more_lawyer.click()
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

    question_short = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']")
    question_long = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@itemprop='text']")
    date_question_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/ul[@class='inline-list']/li[@class='text-muted small hidden-xs']")
    name_lawyers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    lawyer_answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='text']")
    dates = []
    names = []
    answers = []
    for lawyer_answer in lawyer_answers:
        answers.append(lawyer_answer.text)
    for date_question_post in date_question_posts:
        dates.append(date_question_post.text)
    for name_lawyer in name_lawyers:
        names.append(name_lawyer.text)

    name_short = question_short.text
    name_long = question_long.text

    print("\nQuestion: ",name_short, "\n" ,name_long, "\n")
    for date in dates:
        print(date)
    for name in names:
        print("\nLawyer name: ", name)
    for answer in answers:
        print("\nLawyer answer: ", answer)

    return (name_short, name_long, name_lawyer, answer, date_question_post)


def page_pagination(driver):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-2']/a[@class='block-link']")
    urls = []
    for div in divs:
        url = div.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url)
    for url_1 in urls:
        trans = driver.get(url_1)
        time.sleep(2)
        get_content(driver)
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    get_url(driver)
    page_pagination(driver)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```